# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject 2

Tags: java, php, json

**I wanna Login database with e-mail and password and get the information. I dont know that what is my problem because when click the sign in button , 
nothing shows. The error is :**

```
*org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject*.
```

**My login codes :**

```
Button SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signIn);
final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMail);
final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                    if (success) {
                        String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                        String surname = jsonResponse.getString("surname");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UsersMainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", name);

                        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Login Failed Please Try again")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };

        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(email, password, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
        queue.add(loginRequest);
    }
});
```

**My PHP codes :**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","id1519330","****","id1519330");

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
  $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? and password = ? ");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email,$password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id, $name, $surname, $email, $password);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;   

 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){

            $response["success"] = true;  
            $response["name"] = $name;
            $response["surname"] = $surname;
            $response["email"] = $email;
            $response["password"] = $password;

    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Add a popup or a console println to make sure that password and email are strings and not json objects first. Afterwards, you need to check what the actual response is and print out the entire object. You're parsing something wrong somewhere. The error message itself should actually tell you what you're parsing wrong but you didn't include the whole thing,

Comment: There's `Related` section on right side on your screen. With tons of the same question answered.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your response is giving an HTML code (happens when your request doesn't give a status 200. Check your String response by either using a debugger or printing the response and you'll be able to know what's wrong with your request.

Answer (score 0):

It seam be that you `response` is not have correct style of json to parse. Please see [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String))
for more detail and try to to debug to see what is the value of this `response`